# How to write a object oriented Node.js model

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

I am having a lot of trouble writing an object oriented Cat class in Node.js. How can I write a Cat.js class and use it in the following way:

```
// following 10 lines of code is in another file "app.js" that is outside 
// the folder "model"
var Cat = require('./model/Cat.js');

var cat1 = new Cat(12, 'Tom');
cat1.setAge(100);
console.log(cat1.getAge()); // prints out 100 to console

var cat2 = new Cat(100, 'Jerry');
console.log(cat1.equals(cat2)); // prints out false

var sameAsCat1 = new Cat(100, 'Tom');
console.log(cat1.equals(sameAsCat1)); // prints out True
```

How would you fix the following Cat.js class I have written:

```
 var Cat = function() {
    this.fields = {
        age: null,
        name: null
    };

    this.fill = function (newFields) {
        for(var field in this.fields) {
            if(this.fields[field] !== 'undefined') {
                this.fields[field] = newFields[field];
            }
        }
    };

    this.getAge = function() {
        return this.fields['age'];
    };

    this.getName = function() {
        return this.fields['name'];
    };

    this.setAge = function(newAge) {
        this.fields['age'] = newAge;
    };

    this.equals = function(otherCat) {
        if (this.fields['age'] === otherCat.getAge() && 
            this.fields['name'] === otherCat.getName())  {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
};

module.exports = function(newFields) {
    var instance = new Cat();
    instance.fill(newFields);
    return instance;
};
```

Comment: Whether this is the only issue, I cannot say, but you want to test `typeof() !== 'undefined'` in your `fill` function. And because you assign them `null` values, that wouldn't work out anyway, because you'll get 'object' back on `typeof`. If you just assign them as `undefined` and test for that via `typeof()`, it would otherwise appear it should behave as you expect.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you need help with?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [TidBits OoJs](https://github.com/najamelan/TidBits_Javascript_OoJs). It's reliable and gives you about all OO features you might dream of except for multiple inheritance in a simple and natural syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I were to design an object like this, then I would have done like this

```
function Cat(age, name) {       // Accept name and age in the constructor
    this.name = name || null;
    this.age  = age  || null;
}

Cat.prototype.getAge = function() {
    return this.age;
}

Cat.prototype.setAge = function(age) {
    this.age = age;
}

Cat.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.name;
}

Cat.prototype.setName = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Cat.prototype.equals = function(otherCat) {
    return otherCat.getName() == this.getName()
        && otherCat.getAge() == this.getAge();
}

Cat.prototype.fill = function(newFields) {
    for (var field in newFields) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(field) && newFields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
            if (this[field] !== 'undefined') {
                this[field] = newFields[field];
            }
        }
    }
};

module.exports = Cat;     // Export the Cat function as it is
```

And then it can be used like this

```
var Cat = require("./Cat.js");

var cat1 = new Cat(12, 'Tom');
cat1.setAge(100);
console.log(cat1.getAge());                 // 100

var cat2 = new Cat(100, 'Jerry');
console.log(cat1.equals(cat2));             // false

var sameAsCat1 = new Cat(100, 'Tom');
console.log(cat1.equals(sameAsCat1));       // true

var sameAsCat2 = new Cat();
console.log(cat2.equals(sameAsCat2));       // false

sameAsCat2.fill({name: "Jerry", age: 100});
console.log(cat2.equals(sameAsCat2));       // true
```

Comment: @Chingy I am assuming yours. Try with `==` instead of `===` :)

Comment: or now better in ES6.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a class :

```
class Cat {
    fields = {
        age: null,
        name: null
    };

    fill(newFields) {
        for(var field in this.fields) {
            if(this.fields[field] !== 'undefined') {
                this.fields[field] = newFields[field];
            }
        }
    }

    getAge() {
        return this.fields.age;
    }

    setAge(newAge) {
        this.fields.age = newAge;
    }
}

exports.Cat = Cat;
```

Comment: I came to give the same answer and saw this -4 answer, omg. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Asqan maybe because the question asks for JS, not TypeScript. And you can't 'use' TypeScript in the browser, it needs to be compiled to JS first.

Comment: I've removed TypeScript from the answer as really modern JavaScript has the feature (classes) I'm recommending.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine  Person.js code here

```
  exports.person=function(age,name)
    {
        age=age;
        name=name;
        this.setAge=function(agedata)
        {
           age=agedata;
        }
        this.getAge=function()
        {
            return age;
        }
        this.setName=function(name)
        {
            name=name;
        }
        this.getName=function()
        {
            return name;
        }

};
```

call object code:

```
var test=require('./route/person.js');
var person=test.person;
var data=new person(12,'murugan');
data.setAge(13);
console.log(data.getAge());
data.setName('murugan');
console.log(data.getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is **error loop hole** in answers by @thefourtheye, I will describe those below

**Object modelling rules**

- Create empty new object
- Create Filled Object
- Only Initial object should be set by machine/code
- After Initial object assignment Any changes in your object should happen by user interaction only.
- After Initial object assignment Any changes in object by code without user intention is going to add some bugs

**Problem Use case :**

Eg - So when you create filled object , at that time if any property(somedate) is not having any value then due to below code the default value gets assigned to it(somedate) , which is against object modelling rules.

- **Bug**
- *Constructor function is given Dual responsibility* to create new
  & filled object which he mixes up while creating filled object , And
  its going to make mistakes.
- Means there is some buggy code in your app that is going to set values by it self without users intention

  `function Cat(age, name, somedate ) { // Accept name and age in the constructor this.name = name || null; this.age  = age  || null; this.somedate = somedate || new Date(); //there will be lots of usecases like this }`

> **So to solve this Problem i use below JavaScript data model.**

So it allows user to create **filled object Or new object** intentionally only when need any one of them and not messing with each other

```js
class Cat {
    constructor(){
        this.name = null;
        this.age = null;
    }

    initModel (data) {
        this.name = data.name;
        this.age = data.age
    }

    getAge () { return this.age;}

    setAge (age) { this.age = age; }

    getName () {this.name;}

    setName (name) {this.name = name;}

    equals (otherCat) {
        return otherCat.getName() == this.getName()
            && otherCat.getAge() == this.getAge();
    }

    fill (newFields) {
        for (let field in newFields) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(field) && newFields.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
                if (this[field] !== 'undefined') {
                    this[field] = newFields[field];
                }
            }
        }
    };
    
}


let cat1 = new Cat();
cat1.initModel({age : 12,name :'Tom'})
cat1.setAge(100);
console.log(cat1.getAge());                 // 100

let cat2 = new Cat();
cat2.initModel({age : 100,name : 'Jerry'})
console.log(cat1.equals(cat2));             // false

let sameAsCat1 = new Cat({age : 100,name : 'Tom'});
sameAsCat1.initModel({age : 100,name : 'Tom'})
console.log(cat1.equals(sameAsCat1));       // true

let sameAsCat2 = new Cat();
console.log(cat2.equals(sameAsCat2));       // false

sameAsCat2.fill({name: "Jerry", age: 100});
console.log(cat2.equals(sameAsCat2));
```

- **Note :**
- **Constructor** is only used For creating **new Object**
- **InitModel** is only used For creating **filled Object**

Comment: How to use that class on another js file? I've tried `import { Cat } from "./app/models/cat.model.js"` but I got error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`